# What's the correct way to work with strtok?

Tags: c, string, strtok

The following code needs to get two strings and add one string to another(addTo and str). But between every word in str I need to add `#` and at the end of the str I need to add `@`.

addTo is defined as `==> char* bigStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);`
From some reason there is a problem in my code.
I'm guessing it's because of incorrect usge of `strtok`.
I've added a `printf` line that shows me what's the new length and the size of the `temp` word I've got from `strtok` and I keep getting the same word in "temp". Why is that and how should I fix my code?

```
char* addToStr(char* addTo, char* str,int on)
{
    //on ==1 for nun last string to add
    if (str!= NULL) {
        while (str != NULL)
        {
            char* temp = strtok(str, " ");
            if (temp != NULL)
            {
                //printf("%d   %d\n", (int)strlen(temp), (int)strlen(addTo));
                if (addTo==" ") 
                {
                    printf("null\n");
                    int newlength = (strlen(temp) + 3) * sizeof(char);
                    addTo = (char*)malloc(newlength);
                }
                else    
                {
                    int newlength = (strlen(addTo) + strlen(temp) + 3) * sizeof(char);
                    addTo = (char*)realloc(addTo, newlength);
                }
                strcat(addTo, temp);
                if (str != NULL)
                    strcat(addTo, "#");
            }
        }
        if(on)
            strcat(addTo, "@");
        else
            addTo = (char*)realloc(addTo, strlen(addTo)-1);
    }
    return addTo;
}
```

Comment: _whats the correct way to work with strtok_: replacing it with [strsep](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strsep.3.html) (if it is available). `if (addTo==" ")` is wrong, you want `if (strcmp(addTo, " ") == 0)`

Comment: What does `*addTo` contain? Is it initialized to be an empty string?

Comment: As `if (addTo==" ")` will be false due to wrong comparison you will enter your `else`  branch and reach `int newlength = (strlen(addTo) ` which will cause undefined behaviour unless you have set `*addTo=0` before your first call. Another potential issue is `addTo = (char*)realloc(addTo, strlen(addTo)-1);` where you chop the memory for the last character as well as the terminating 0 byte and do not terminate the string again.

Answer (score 0):

You're wrongly using strtok because you're always starting from the beginning of your string by writing `char* temp = strtok(str, " ");`.

check [here](https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) for more information.

In your case you should do something like :

```
char* temp = strtok(str, " "); //The second argument corresponds to delimiters characters, maybe you should also add " ,.-"
while (temp != NULL)
{
    ... //do your stuff with temp
    temp = strtok (NULL, " "); //If first argument is NULL, strtok keeps scanning from where it ended at previous call.
}
```

You're also wrongly using pointers, you can't write :

```
if (addTo==" ")
```

because `addTo` conresponds to an adress. To check the pointed data, you need to do something like `addTo[i]` or `*(addTo + i)` where `i` corresponds to the index.

Comment: I have changed my code by your advice, but in the first run Im getting invalids chars in addTo, which is declarer like this==> char* bigStr = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*1);                                     whats the right to write this one?

Comment: Can you show me how you are using your `addToStr` in your main ?